# How to reload just CSS styles using react-hot-loader?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, react-hot-loader, hot-reload

I have some React app in development, it is not small (CRM like, many components featuring CRUD operations). We were using hot reloading but it wasn't comfortable, it didn't reload redux-sagas properly, so we turned it off.

We would like to bring back hot reloading partially - just for stylesheets. The way react-hot-loader I would like to work is to watch on *.less files changes and reload them if needed. We are using Webpack 3.9, Less 3.0 and less-loader 4.0